# Decrypting message from nodejs on c++ libgcrypt

Tags: c++, node.js, aes, libgcrypt

I have been able to encrypt and decrypt a message on the client application as well as the server. I am having issues when sending a message from the server and decrypting it on the client.

**Server**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
server.listen({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: PORT,
    exclusive: false
}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        logger.error(`Error starting server ${err}`);
    }
    else console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
}).on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.setTimeout(1500);
    socket.state = new ClientState(socket);
    clients.push(socket);
    logger.info(`${socket.state.name} connected `);
    // Handle incoming messages from clients.
    socket.on('data', async (data) => {
       let jsontString = encryptToken('test');
       console.log("Sending this to client: " + jsontString);
       socket.write(jsontString);
    });

function encryptToken(token){
    var key = 'one test AES key';

    token = "test";

    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-128-ecb", key, '');

    let encrypted = cipher.update(token, 'utf8', 'hex');

    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');

    console.log("Encrypted token: "+ encrypted.toString('hex'));

    return encrypted.toString('hex'); 
}
```

//Output:

```
Encrypted token: 7876427539d4ea70f6a4aa20d247adcb
```

This token value reaches the client side. Here is the client code:

**Client**

//main.cpp

```
#include "aes.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   //socket code..
   aes rijndael_ = aes("one test AES key");
   serverAnswer = socket_.sendReceive(buf);   //buf = encrypted token that came from server

   std::vector<char> resp(serverAnswer.begin(), serverAnswer.end());

   std::string decryptAnswer = rijndael_.decrypt(resp);
   std::cout << "Decrypted: " << decryptAnswer << std::endl;
}
```

//output: Decrypted: ��wΓ��o@՛B��%C��B�ƌ�ǝ]��q

The decrypt function does not give me any error codes.. The block bytes are padded as a multiple of 16.. else I would get an invalid length error. I also noticed that the server outputs a different hex encryption from the client if trying to encrypt the string 'test' with AES128-ecb.

//aes.cpp

```
#include "aes.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#define GCRY_CIPHER GCRY_CIPHER_AES128   // Pick the cipher here
#define GCRY_MODE GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_ECB // Pick the cipher mode here

aes::aes(std::string k)
{
    key_ = k;
    keyLength_ = gcry_cipher_get_algo_keylen(GCRY_CIPHER);
    gcry_control (GCRYCTL_DISABLE_SECMEM, 0);
    gcry_control (GCRYCTL_INITIALIZATION_FINISHED, 0);
    gcry_cipher_open(&handle, GCRY_CIPHER, GCRY_MODE, 0);
    gcry_cipher_setkey(handle, key_.c_str(), keyLength_);
}

std::string aes::decrypt(std::vector<char> const& text) { 
    gcry_error_t gcryError;
    std::cout << "the size is " << text.size() << std::endl

    size_t textLength = text.size();

    std::cout << "textLength:: " << textLength << std::endl;

    gcry_cipher_final(handle); 
    char * decBuffer = new char[textLength];
    gcryError = gcry_cipher_decrypt(handle, decBuffer, textLength, text.data(), textLength);

    if(gcryError)
    {
        printf("gcry_cipher_decrypt failed: %s/%s\n", gcry_strsource(gcryError), gcry_strerror(gcryError));
    }

    printf("outtBuffer = %s\n", decBuffer);

    std::string ret (decBuffer);

    delete [] decBuffer;
    return ret;
}
```

I come here asking for help after spending a full day of trying to tinker with the code and having no luck. Any tips to guide me in the right direction are appreciated. Let me know if there's any more code I need to provide. I did my best to make this somewhat of a MCV considering the fact that there are 2 applications running.

Comment: "The decrypt function does not give me any error codes" - of course it doesn't. It does *not know* what the correct decrypted output looks like. It just goes through the motions to decrypt and gives you the result.

Comment: Right. I made that statement to clarify that I don't think I am missing anything when it comes to block byte size or a non-matching key.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That  might eve answer that question appropriately enough.

Comment: If it was not clear in the question, I am obviously trying to find out why the client is not decrypting properly after following the protocol to decrypt a message that was encrypted using AES128 on ECB mode